# Can we show 3 Yvalues on chart control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application on which there are 2 chart control as follows:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
           Height="589px" Width="1109px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelAngle="90" 
                    XValueMember="Question" YValueMembers="YesCounter">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY Title="Number of Yes">
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX Title="Questions"  IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                <LabelStyle Angle="90" Interval="1" />
            </AxisX>
            <Position Height="94" Width="50" X="3" Y="3" />
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

and

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
           Height="589px" Width="1109px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelAngle="90" 
                    XValueMember="Question" YValueMembers="NoCounter">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY Title="Number of No">
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX Title="Questions"  IsLabelAutoFit="False">
                <LabelStyle Angle="90" Interval="1" />
            </AxisX>
            <Position Height="94" Width="50" X="3" Y="3" />
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Now I want to show one single chart that contains questions on the X-axis and a "yes,no" count on the Y-axis. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use stacked bar chart.  Something like this http://www.dotnetcharting.com/gallery/view.aspx?id=Gallery/a03